# How I can implement a notifications system in real time using Yii2?

Tags: events, websocket, yii2, notifications, frameworks

I want to implement a notification system using the Yii2 framework.
I think that using events and a websocket, maybe I can solve, but I have no idea how.

What I want is to notify the different logged-in users about the occurrence of a certain event such as the creation of a new invoice record in the Database, the payment of an invoice, etc.

Maybe someone has already done something similar can help me with a real code.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have events on your models. You need a websocket, and when those (or desired) events are fired, just send a notification over your websocket to update any relevant data you wish.